# The survey banner on Jobs needs some space

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, design

I visited [Stack Overflow Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) (don't ask) when my untrained eye noticed that something seemed off in the layout of the short survey banner:

[image: survey banner with text we want your feedback and button Take our 3 minute survey. Text is left top aligend with no whitespace]

How that text hugs the top and left edge and with that button squeezed in is how my attempt at styling would end. I guess a CSS rule doesn't get applied there, probably one that adds padding or margin (never know when to apply which).

I repro-ed this on Chrome, Edge and Firefox with plugins disabled (logged in and anonymous). All tests done on Windows 10.

Please give that banner some space. It deserves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rene, thanks for reporting this! We deployed a fix today.